# Importando um controle objc em swift: Erro ao por uma ação (func) do meu contole

Tags: objective-c, api, importação, swift, controles

Resolvi fazer um app em swift desta vez, e como de costume uso meu controle personalizado (MenuView).
No objC eu sei como funciona e tudo funcionava, no swift eu segui todos os passos, importar no bridging-header.h, e colocar o MenuViewDelegate que eu criei também.

Ate ai tudo bem, sem erro
[image: Codigo swift importando o controle MenuView]
Quando eu pus o comando que criei no controle

```
func MenuView(MenuView: MenuView!, didTouch sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer!) {

}
```

apareceu o seguinte erro:(Use of undeclared type 'MenuView') apontando todas as linhas que continham o objeto do "Menuview"
[image: Codigo swift importando o controle com erro]

Como eu procedo para corrigir isto ?? Eu fiz algo errado, esqueci de alguma coisa...
Agradeço desde já alguma ajuda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existe um conflito entre o nome da classe `MenuView` e a assinatura do método delegate que também chama `MenuView`.
Em Objective-C, a assinatura do método é `MenuView:didTouch`, mas em Swift ele é apenas `MenuView` e gesture sender não aparece no nome.

Neste caso, para que não ocorra conflito, seguindo o design pattern do Cocoa o nome do método deveria ser `- (void)menuView:(MenuView *)menuView didTouch:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender;`

Comment: De fato, o erro sumiu. Mas quando essa ação é iniciada o app da erro na linha 14 (fatal error). O que pode ser ??

Comment: Não entendi sua dúvida. O app vai quebrar com certeza, pois é o que a linha 14 faz. Se você remover o `init` que está quebrando (linha 13 a 15) não irá quebrar mais.